# Python and Tkinter: Function madness

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write myself a program that calculates a function taken from a Tk.Entry().
The problem is, when I try to run my display() function
(it runs Tkinter, sets up the window, and calls root.Mainloop()),
I get parse errors coming from eval() from a function that is supposed to be called **only** if the user inputs all of the variables and presses a button (the button's command).
The function uses eval(variable), while variable is entry.get().
What am I doing wrong here?

```
def cfunc(_n,_f,_t0,_tn,):  
 xbase=[]  
 tbase=[]  
 t=0      
 n2=eval(_n)  #Stuff happens here, cfunc gets entry_n.get() as arguments.  
 f2=_f  #Also, tabs are correct in the original.  
 tmin2=eval(_t0)  
 tmax2=eval(_tn)  
 tr=tmax2-tmin2  
 sk = tr / n2  
 i2=tmin2
```

Also, error:

> File "Q:\Py\counter.py", line 89, in
>   cfunc
>       n2=eval(_n)   File "", line 0
>           ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Could you please post the error and possibly __part__ of the code that causes the errors?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code. From the symptoms I'd say you're evaluating something too early instead of wrapping it e.g. in a lambda

Comment: We can't know what exactly causes this, but no matter whether `eval` plays a part in it or not: Using `eval` is the real madness ;)

Comment: Help, anyone? I have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown us the code that causes the error (the value of _n) so we can only guess. A couple words of advice:

1. the error message is telling you the problem: unexpected eof. That means there's a missing closing quote or brace or something like that. The parser got to the end of the "file" (the string being eval'd) before it got the characters it expected.
2. put a print statement immediately before an eval, and use some special characters to delimit it (eg: puts ">>>$_n<<<") so you can tell precisely what is in the string being eval'd, including any leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: I found it, I forgot to put cfunc() in button command in brackets.  
Silly, silly me.